# Remove newline from for looped words

Tags: python

I am trying to remove the new lines from for-looped words of a paragraph.

code.py

```
paragraph = 'How are you'

for word in paragraph:
    print(word)
```

Output:

```
>> H
>> o
>> w
>> 
>> a
>> r
>> e
>>
>> y
>> o
>> u
```

code.py

```
for word in paragraph:
    remove_spacing = ''
    new_word = word.replace('\n', '')
```

It is not changing at all.

I am trying to first loop all the words then attach after it

I also tried using:

```
new_word = word.rstrip("\n\r")
```

Expected Output:

```
>> Howareyou
```

I have tried many times but it is still not working.

Comment: Replace spaces with empty string using [`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace).

Comment: Yes, I have edited my answer it was a mistake, I also tried this, But it is still not working

Comment: The string doesn't actually contain a newline. `print()` is putting one in.

Comment: To get your expected output, `print(paragraph.replace(' ','')`. I don't know why you're doing the stuff you're doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to use something like this:

```
paragraph = 'How are you' 
words = paragraph.split()#get just the words
for word in words: #for each word
    print(word, end='')#print and don't go to newline
```

This will print each word without going to a new line.

Output:

```
Howareyou
```

If you want to save to a variable use this:

```
paragraph = 'How are you' 
words = paragraph.split()#get just the words
var = ''
for word in words: #for each word
    var += word
print(var)
```

Output:

```
Howareyou
```

Two simpler forms are:

```
var = "".join(paragraph.split())
print(var)
#and
var = paragraph.replace(" ","")
print(var)
```

These save to `var` in the same way.

Comment: I am trying to first loop all the words then attach after it

Comment: What do you mean by attach? @rec

Comment: This code matches your expected output

Comment: Yeah, this matches the expected output so if this does not answer your question please explain and I can update my answer to accommodate.

Comment: @EliHarold, Thanks it worked

Comment: How can `assign`  **print(word, end='')** into variable ? When I do it like, `new_word = word,end=''` then it says `"ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)"`

Comment: @rec, you can't. `print()` is the function which print value either to system stdout of file. If your task is to remove spaces from string - use `str.replace()`.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier `str.replace()` doesn't work, You can try it by yourself.

Comment: @rec see the updated answer I show how to save it to a variable.

Comment: Thanks again. It Worked

Comment: @rec, it's impossible that `str.replace()` doesn't work.

Comment: I did wonder about "why it didn't work". I think you should try it, If it works for you, then please let me know

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't understand, Can you explain in brief please ? If i understand correctly you mean about `double quotes` ?

Comment: You should understand that "str" is the generic name, in your case you don't have to call the .replace method on "str" but on "paragraph" instead.

Comment: @rec see the new addition to my answer it gives 2 easier forms.

Comment: Thanks but I am checking on every word's alphabet not on whole word, in which `replace` didn't worked